How to detect if a specific font style is installed?
How do I detect if a specific style of a font family is installed within the family?
In some VCL projects, I have a UI that uses Roboto Bold. If the user has Roboto installed, but not the specific Roboto Bold style font, the system will substitute Roboto and "bold" it, which results in a slightly wider spacing which sometimes results in an unexpected line wrap.
I can easily detect if Roboto is installed with Screen.Fonts.IndexOf('Roboto'), but that returns true even if Roboto Bold is not installed. And Roboto Bold does not show up in Screen.Fonts, since that list only shows family names.
How can I drill down within the family to see which actual fonts are installed?

Ken, Thanks, but unfortunately that does not work.  That's in fact the issue. Roboto Bold is never in Screen.Fonts, since the system condenses the listing to just Roboto.  The result is -1 whether Roboto Bold is there or not.

Since Screen.Fonts condenses the list to avoid duplicates, you will have to call the Win32 EnumFontFamiliesEx() function directly to get the full font list, or even to just search for a specific font.

Thanks, Remi.  I'll see if I can make that work.

working from Stijn's answer, I edited a bit to make it work for me. Font is installed if IsFontInstalled returns 0
function CheckFontCB(const lf:TLogFont;const tm:TTextMetric;ft:DWORD;lParam:NativeInt):integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result:=0;//found one! EnumFontFamiliesEx can stop enumerating now, and will return 0
end;

function IsFontInstalled(const x:string):integer;
var
  i,l:integer;
  lf:TLogFont;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lf,SizeOf(TLogFont));
  lf.lfCharSet:=DEFAULT_CHARSET;
  l:=Length(x);
  if l>=LF_FACESIZE then raise Exception.Create('Invalid font name length');
  for i:=0 to l-1 do lf.lfFaceName[i]:=x[i+1];
  lf.lfFaceName[l]:=#0;
  Result:=EnumFontFamiliesEx(GetDC(0),lf,@CheckFontCB,0,0);
end;

Thanks!
Scott

A better fix would have left IsFontInstalled returning a boolean, and changed the last line to Result := EnumFontFamiliesEx(GetDC(0),lf,@CheckFontCB,0,0) = 0;. IsFontInstalled should be returning a True or False to match its name. It's also easier to use as if IsFontInstalled then rather than if (IsFontInstalled = 0) then.

Definitely better, yes. Thanks. I got lazy and was just happy to have something that worked.

I have been using this:
function CheckFontCB(const lf:TLogFont;const tm:TTextMetric;ft:DWORD;lParam:NativeInt):integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result:=0;//found one! EnumFontFamiliesEx can stop enumerating now, and will return 0
end;

function IsFontInstalled(const x:string):boolean;
var
  i,l:integer;
  lf:TLogFont;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lf,SizeOf(TLogFont));
  lf.lfCharSet:=DEFAULT_CHARSET;
  l:=Length(x);
  if l>=LF_FACESIZE then raise Exception.Create('Invalid font name length');
  for i:=0 to l-1 do lf.lfFaceName[i]:=x[i+1];
  lf.lfFaceName[l]:=#0;
  Result:=EnumFontFamiliesEx(GetDC(0),lf,@CheckFontCB,0,0)=0;
end;


Stijn,  Thanks.  I just tried this and am getting an error on the Result line of IsFontInstalled.  Error is Incompatible types boolean and integer.  Any chance there's a typo?

Thanks, yes I had a mistake there. Not sure why, I guess I may have an auto-convert from LongBool to boolean or something.
